# Strange autocomplete suggestions in IPython Shell

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython

I use the IPython shell fairly often and have just started to notice it giving me strange autocomplete suggestions without any prompting from me. In this example, I just typed "im" and it suggests importing matplotlib?
[image]

This is very strange for several reasons: I've never seen this kind of grayed out code suggestion before that appears just as I type without the need to press tab or anything like that, the suggestions seem to be very arbitrary (why would typing im mean I want to import matplotlib of all things) and sometimes the suggestions make so sense (image 2: it just asks me to run plt.show() even though I haven't plotted anything yet).

[image]

Any clues to what could be going on here?

Comment: Did you recently update ipython?  Perhaps this is a new feature?

Comment: 1) I consider IPython 8.x a work in progress and am sticking with 7.x for the time being 2) See [Changes](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.0/whatsnew/version8.html) `Autosuggestons`(sic). One of the reasons I am not moving up yet.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Your right, it must be the Autosuggestons beta, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Thanks for the link @AdrianKlaver. So to use the autosuggestion: press C-e, C-f, or right arrow to complete. You should post an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
import IPython
terminal = IPython.get_ipython()
terminal.pt_app.auto_suggest = None
```

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/13451